# Setting a Flash text field value using JavaScript without using ExternalInterface (I DO NOT have control of the SWF)

Tags: javascript, flash, xul

I created a FireFox extension which our customer service agents use to put predefined support responses into various CRM systems.

It was easy; get the active element, determine range of existing text and update the value with existing text plus the new text.

My problem is that one of the CRM systems is written in Flash.

I do not have control of the Flash so I can't use ExternalInterface.

I find this entire problem troubling.  I can easily use control-v to paste text into any Flash field...why can't it be done with JavaScript???

Thank you.

Eric

Comment: Perhaps some of the [tools](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1250/looking-for-a-test-tool-for-flash-based-web-applications-any-ideas) that people use to automate tests for Flash applications would help you solve this.